# Android: Button Onclick event

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-button

I want to change the color back to default color.

If suppose I click on the Button; the color of button must change. And if I click on the same Button again... the color must set back to default.

How can I achieve this...

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clicked) {
                    holder.b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_icon_hover);
                } else {
                    holder.b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_icon);
                }
                clicked = false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clicked) {
                holder.b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_icon_hover);
                clicked = false;
            } else {
                holder.b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_icon);
                clicked = true;
            }

        }
    });
```

Or Create a `Selector` in `drawable/selector.xml` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
   android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/like_icon_hover" />
  <item
   android:state_pressed="false"
   android:drawable="@drawable/like_icon" />
 </selector>
```

And set this `Selector` as a `Background` to your `Button` like:

```
android:background="@drawable/selector"
```

Comment: simple and nice answer,,,

Comment: I'm trying to do the same but asks me to end or holder can not be accessed from the event click

Answer (score 0):

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (clicked) {
                holder.b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_icon_hover);
            } else {
                holder.b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_icon);
            }
            clicked = !clicked;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same but asks me to end or holder can not be accessed from the event click